# Do I lose anything with an empty offhand?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am leveling up a monk and I have a great 1H weapon (L70 ancient legendary with a huge level requirement reduction).

Unfortunately I don't have a second weapon that is anywhere near as good, so I'm wondering what to use in my other hand.

What happens if I just leave it empty?  Will my mainhand swing twice as often?

What about equipping a shield?  Do I lose mainhand swings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should equip a shield in your off hand if you have no comparable weapons.

You get a 15% attack speed boost for equipping two weapons, but you alternate attacks with one, then the other. This means that if the weapons are comparable, you get bonus damage, but if one weapon is significantly better, the time wasted attacking with the lesser weapon will actually decrease your DPS.

If you only have a single weapon equipped, you don't get the attack speed boost, but you do attack with your good weapon every attack. You do not lose any attack speed by equipping a shield, so you might as well find one (no matter how lame it is), because it's better than nothing.